# how to check whether expression in a part of another expression

Tags: algorithm, graph, symbolic-math

Is there an efficient algorithm/data structure to find that one arithmetic expression is a part of another arithmetic expression. The expression consists of unknown variables like `a`, `b`, `c`, constansts like `56`, and arithmetic operations: `*`, `+`, `-`, `/` with braces.

Examples:
`a+b` is subpart of `b+a`

`2*a+b` is subpart of `3*a+b`

`a*a+b` is subpart of `a(a+c) + b`

Comment: Your question leaves it unclear what your exact definition of "subpart" is. E.g. I find it surprising to call `2*a+b` a subpart of `3*a+b`. So you are using the term in a different interpretation than mine.

Comment: As far as I understand finding "subparts" even with the usual definition is complicated. An additional complication here is that for "a*(a+c)+b+d" it seems that both "a*a+b" and "a*a+d" will be sub-parts, but not at the same time - and neither is a sub-part of the other. For symbolic math it will also depend on your actual use: code generation, understandable output, etc.

Comment: The non-algebraic part of this is, I think called "unification" or "pattern matching" in a computer science context; maybe cs.stackexchange.com is an appropriate audience. The algebraic part, where you recognize that a + b is a subexpression of a + 2 b, etc., makes the problem a lot more complicated. The first thing that comes to mind is that one considers, implicitly or explicitly, all expressions equivalent to the matched-to expression, and asks if the would-be subexpression is a literal subexpression of any of them. Maybe there is an efficient way to carry out that search.